# El succes de Ajax no esta funcionando

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

Actualmente tengo una llamada jax que me lleva a mi metodo de C# para poder hacer la autenticacion de mi usuario, pero dicha llamada de Ajax no esta funcionando la parte del succes, ya que si me manda al metodo que quiero pero al final no me manda el alerta que deberia de mandar al pasar por succes:

Codigo de Ajax

```
function autenticarme() {
    var nick = $(".txtNick").val(); 
    var pass = $(".txtPass").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "login.aspx/conectarBD",
        data: "{ nick: '" + nick + "',password: '" + pass + "' }",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Entro");
        }, error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Codigo del metodo de C#

```
#region conectarBD
[WebMethod]
public static string conectarBD(string nick,string password)
{
    Conexion conn = new Conexion();
    string respuesta = conn.Autentificar(nick,password);
    return respuesta;


}
#endregion
```

Comment: ¿La petición está llegando al *code behind*, es decir, al código de C#?

Comment: @Flxtr si llega a C#, lo debugeo y pasa por todo el recorrido pero cuando ya lo hizo todo en C# y regresa a javascript. solo se termina y no me manda el mensaje.

Comment: Creo que ya sé dónde está el error, el AjaxRequest espera un `true` en la respuesta, y como en el `string` `return respuesta;` no lo llevas por eso siempre te manda al `error`. Hagamos una prueba, en el código C# ponle `return "{ success : true }";`. Si todo sale correcto, tendrás que serializar la respuesta a formato JSON para que el Ajax sepa que todo salió bien :) Voy a poner una respuesta para que te des una idea de cómo sería

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en el parámetro dataType: "json" que estás usando en la consulta AJAX.

Este parámetro le indica a jQuery el formato que vendrá desde el servidor. Es decir, en este caso estás indicándole que vendrá un JSON, lo cual no está ocurriendo. Solo le estás enviando texto plano por eso te ejecutará la función de error. Si eliminas este parámetro, jQuery asumirá que solo vendrá texto plano.

Por lo que veo que hay dos opciones:

1) O eliminás este parámetro y retornás un string en C#, tal cual está hecho ahora.

2) O bien, cambiás el método de C# para que retorne un JSON. Cambiando el return por:

```
return {data: respuesta};
```

Answer (score 0):

Independientemente que el flujo de la petición se haya completado, el *Ajax Request* espera como resultado un `success: true` para poder saber sí todo salió de forma correcta, caso contrario, siempre estaría llegando al `error`.

En el `Code Behind` tendrás que serializar la respuesta para enviar el resultado como exitoso:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object conectarBD(string nick, string password)
{
    try{
        Conexion conn = new Conexion();
        string respuesta = conn.Autentificar(nick,password);

        return new { success = true, data = respuesta };
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return new { success = false, data = e.Message };
    }
}
```